# Getting logged in user details in oracle fusion

Tags: oracle-adf

I have developed a custom adf application and deployed in oracle fusion cloud .I need the fusion cloud logged in user's name .Is there anyway to get it in my adf application.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If your app is hosted as a sso enabled and has ADF security  , you can use ADFSecurity context to get the details of the user, if the user is authenticated into your application

```
ADFContext.getCurrent().getSecurityContext().getUserName()
```

Comment: thank you but wait i will explain my scenario I have developed a adf application and deployed in SAAS extension (jcs) and i have given my application as an external application(url) in fusion.When fusion user login he have my application as a url .I need to get that user name i.e logged in user atleast. Any ways ????